# Can't resolve the reference (Xamarin build iOS)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm trying to debug my application on iOS Simulator but I'm getting this Error with no more description:

> Can't resolve the reference 'System.IntPtr System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal::GetIDispatchForObject(System.Object)', referenced from the method 'System.IntPtr System.Dynamic.ComEventSinkProxy::SupportsInterface(System.Guid&)' in 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  MyApp.iOS

There is no Error Code or Error Line or File or anything more. I can successfully debug my app on Android Simulator and successfully debug new template app on iOS Simulator. but when I try to Debug this app on iOS, I get this and I don't have any idea that what is this reference as I never used it in my app. :(

Comment: Are you getting any stack traces that you could provide? Please add some more info on when this is exception/error is happening (e.g. at the launch of the app)?

Comment: @Ale_lipa No, the build fails.

Comment: Likely some third party library that you are consuming?   We would need to know what is that exaactly, as the above looks like some COM stuff being pulled in.